# regexp: how to remove the beginning of the path

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a regular expression that parse gcc compilation output:

```
^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$
```

The first sub expression - `^(..[^:]*)` mark the file where error occurs.

For example, for this input:

```
main.c:1156:13: error: invalid storage class
```

It will mark

```
main.c
```

and for this input:

```
folder/main.c:1156:13: error: invalid storage class
```

It will mark

```
folder/main.c
```

How can I change the first sub expression to mark only the file name without the full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest replacing the `(..[^:]*)` with `(?:[^\r\n:]*/)?([^:\r\n]*)`:

```
^(?:[^\r\n:]*/)?([^:\r\n]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6Kkjn/1)

The change part matches:

- `(?:[^\r\n:]*/)?`  - 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `[^\r\n:]*` - zero or more chars other than `:`, CR and LF and then
  - `/` - a `/` char
- `([^:\r\n]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `:`, CR and LF